# Mounting Framless Shower Door To Fibergalss Shower Insert

Tags: shower, fastener

I purchased online a 3/8" glass frameless swing door with panel for my fiberglass shower insert.  I am struggling with hanging the door. I put the molly anchors (plastic looks like they were designed for tile) in the holes I drilled and they just dropped into the insert since they had no lip. There are two door hinges with four 2" screws each.  There is a stud, but it is is approx 2 1/4" in.  Any recommendations for mounting the hinges?  Read some folks say not to install into the studs since it could pull the fiberglass in, others say it could not be done, and others mention SNAPTOGGLE Toggle Bolts. Would prefer to find anchors that I can use with the nickel plated screws. The company I orderd from ensured me before I bought that I could install their framless door in fiberglass, and when asked today said I could just use the molly anchors they sent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install it with screws into the studs. You will need to find longer screws than those supplied, preferably stainless steel. You may have to go to a marine supply store. When fastening you will need to take care not to over drive the screws, which could distort or even crack the fiberglass surround. The surround itself is not substantial enough to use with anchors for supporting the door.

Comment: +1... just be aware that stainless fasteners can be more brittle than normal screws, so predrill and be careful when driving.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. One important detail I left out, I can only hit the studs on the right two screws of the upper and lower hinge.  For the ones on the left, i need to use some type of molley or toggle.